# C++17 std::optional error: expected primary-expression before 'auto'

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++17, stdoptional

I was experimenting with C++17 feature [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

The optional return type is `std::optional<std::pair<int, int>>`. I call the 
`sum_pair` function in `print_answer` function and wanted a optional print.

In `print_answer` function I wanted to check whether the required pair holds something to show.
like in the example given in: [optional-returning factory functions are usable as conditions of while and if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Following is the code: [here is it live with error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YhBQ9aZ2SBrMNRpZ)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <optional>

typedef std::optional<std::pair<int, int>> returnType;

// following algorithum works fine: just to show, 
// how I have used the std::optional
returnType sum_pair(const std::vector<int>& vec, const int sum)
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> compIndexMap;

    int index = 0;
    for(const int& ele: vec)
    {
        if(auto check = compIndexMap.find(sum - ele); check != compIndexMap.cend())
            return returnType{std::make_pair(check->second, index)};

        compIndexMap.emplace(sum - ele, index);
        ++index;
    }
    return std::nullopt;
}

// problem is here:
void print_answer(const std::vector<int>& vec, const int sum)
{
    // if I uncomment the if-else, everything works
    /*if*/(auto Pair = sum_pair(vec, sum) )?  
        std::cout << "Resulting indexes are: " << Pair->first << " " << Pair->second << std::endl: //;
    //else
        std::cout << "Nothing found!\n";
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec0{ 1,3,2,8 };
    const int sum = 8;
    print_answer(vec0, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

When I use the `if-else` statement in the following format

```
(condion) ? print something: print something else;
```

I get the following two errors. (used GCC 7.1)

```
||=== Build: Debug in MyTestProgram (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
|25|error: expected primary-expression before 'auto'|
|25|error: expected ')' before 'auto'|
```

Can somebody explain, why I need to use if-else, but not with **"operator ?"** ?

Comment: `auto anything = something` is not a valid expression. It's a declaration, and declarations are not valid expressions. And the ternary expression is not an if-else statement.

Comment: @n.m. sorry did not get your point. How come then [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/s27RImEB2zP1Hhqk) works?

Comment: Let me try again. A *? operator* is not an *if-else statement*, and not everything that is acceptable in the latter is acceptable in the former.

Comment: @Malayalam would you expect `(int x = 17) ? x + 3 : x + 5` to compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(auto Pair = sum_pair(vec, sum) )
    std::cout << "Resulting indexes are: " << Pair->first << " " << Pair->second << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "Nothing found!\n";
```

this is valid C++.  You are allowed to put a declaration in the opening condition of an  `if` clause.

```
(auto Pair = sum_pair(vec, sum) )?
    std::cout << "Resulting indexes are: " << Pair->first << " " << Pair->second << std::endl
:
    std::cout << "Nothing found!\n";
```

this is not valid C++.  Declarations are not expressions.  There are places where expressions are allowed, but declararions are not.  The left hand side of `?`, the trinary operator, is one of them.